# I can not log in with Auth::attempt php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I receive data from the login form, but for some reason it is not authorized. The data is correctly saved to the database. I'm new to laravel and I don't understand at all why this is happening, but I want to know.
login.blade.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request){
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('user.private'));
        }

$formFields = $request->only(['email','password']);
        if (Auth::attempt($formFields)){

            return redirect(route('user.private'));
        }
        return redirect(route('user.login'))->withErrors([

            'email' => 'Bad'
        ]);

    }
}
```

LoginController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request){
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('user.private'));
        }

$formFields = $request->only(['email','password']);
        if (Auth::attempt($formFields)){

            return redirect(route('user.private'));
        }
        return redirect(route('user.login'))->withErrors([

            'email' => 'Bad'
        ]);

    }
}
```

web.php:

```
<?php
Route::name('user.')->group(function (){
    Route::view('/private','private')->middleware('auth')->name('private');
    Route::get('/login',function(){
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('user.private'));
        }
//        Проверка на авторизацию пользователя. Если уже авторизован, то редирект на страницу профиля
        return view('login');
    })->name('login');
    Route::post('/login',[\App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class,'login']);
    Route::get('/logout',function(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    })->name('logout');
    Route::get('/registration', function () {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('user.private'));
        }
        return view('registration');
    })->name('registration');
    Route::post('/registration',[\App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController::class,'save']);
});
```

From database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3AQS.png)
From startup/login
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu2KR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Laravel's documentation for this, it seems your code is a little different: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users

As a cleanup note, I'd remove the Auth::check in your web.php as you have already included it in your login controller.

Comment: The password in the database is not hashed

Comment: Doesnt work. It is the same code, but with validation

Comment: I can hash password with this 
```
 
    public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    }
```
But it is doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The password field value in the database can't be a clear one, you need to bcrypt it.

Got to the console and run `php artisan tinker` then put the result of bcrypt as the value of the field

```
User::where('email','test1234@test')->update(['password' => bcrypt('test')]);
```

Now you can login with `test1234@test` as email and `test` as password

Comment: I already try to hash password with ``` 
    public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    }``` in User.php, but it is same doesnt work

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздиенко use bcrypt or adjust the Hash to 12 rounds https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#adjusting-the-bcrypt-work-factor understand that `Auth::attempt()` is so basic in laravel it can't be buggy. the only remaining possible issue is your data. either the database or the request data

Answer (score 0):

Password had to be hashed via `bcrypt`:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value) {
         $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    }

}
```

So you can use simpy

```
Auth::attempt(array('email' => 'test1234@test', 'password' => 'test'));
```